# How to maintain the unique id for every request in spring

Tags: spring

I need to maintain a unique Id for every request, Because we writing info and error log in a different file, In order to trace for this request1 we got this error and info message. I am passing the Unicode as an additional parameter for every method, this looks bad. Any alternative option available in spring to handle this stuff.

sample Trace Id:

info-file.log

```
uniqueId1 request1
```

error-file.log

```
uniqueId1 error1
uniqueId2 error2
```

To achieve this we passing the uniqueId in every method of controller,service and dao layer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use log4j, you can use this once at the very start of your controller/service

```
MDC.put("uniqueId", your id here);
```

Then, in your log4j config, you can use %X{uniqueId} like this :

```
log4j.appender.default.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c [%X{uniqueId}] -> %m%n
```

When you are done (at the end of the request) you simply do :

```
MDC.remove("uniqueId");
```

Comment: When using SLF4j this is abstracted and you are basically free to choose which ever logging framework.

Comment: @wesker317 thanks for the suggestion on MDC. Also, I am not aware of it, will learn and use it. we using SLF4j with logback.xml configuration.